# MSE, is it correct to use evaluate with unscaled data in Tensorflow Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mse

Suppose you have numerical time series data and you managed to split it like:

> X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test.

and you properly scaled everything ending up with:

> X_train_scaled, y_train_scaled, X_val_scaled, y_val_scaled,
> X_test_scaled, y_test_scaled

And now you run the following code:

```
linear = Sequential([
    Dense(units=1,activation='linear',input_shape=[X_train_scaled.shape[1])
    ])

linear.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')

history = linear.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_scaled,
                     epochs=50, verbose=1, shuffle=False,
                      validation_data=(X_valid_scaled.values,y_valid_scaled.values))
```

If our idea is to calculate the MSE, we can use the ***scaled test data*** and calculate it by 2 "different" ways:

```
mse_linear_scaled_1   = linear.evaluate(X_test_scaled,y_test_scaled)
```

or using the standalone version from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError

```
mse                   = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
mse_linear_scaled_2   = mse(y_test_scaled.values,y_pred_scaled).numpy()
```

if you do this exercise, *mse_linear_scaled_1 = mse_linear_scaled_2* (as expected).

Now here comes the question (thank you if you read down to here...). If you do this same last part but with the ***original scale*** of the test data (the final idea is to get the RMSE value to have it in context of the real data) the results are very different between each other.

```
mse_linear_unscaled_1 = linear.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

gives a very different number than doing

```
mse_linear_unscaled_2 = mse(y_test,y_pred).numpy()
```

If I want to get the correct RMSE number in the scale of the original time series numbers, would guess this should be the correct way of doing it?

```
np.sqrt(mse_linear_unscaled_2)
```

Maybe `.evaluate()` wasn't thought for this and is doing something under the hood that I'm not aware, so it won't return the correct number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `linear.evaluate(,)` you are using the model `linear` that was already fitted with scaled data. So evaluating with unscaled data is like introducing a range of data that that particular model did not see.

The way to go is, in pseudocode:

```
y_pred_scaled = linear.predict(y_test_scaled) 
inverse_transform y_pred_scaled with your scaler 
mse in original scale comparing y_test to y_pred
```